# Is 404 error due to web-app version?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I keep getting this 404 error :

```
HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report
message 
description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/5.5.33
```

I know the different files in webapps folder, and I just added a new file folder and I keep getting the above error.

Could it be because of the different version on the web-app the ones that works is :

```
<web-app id="sxrl-2013.2" version="2.4" ...>
```

and the not working one is :

```
<web-app version="3.0" id="sxrl-2014.1.0" ...>
```

Being new to this I'm not sure where I can check what is going on wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server doesn't support **Servlets 3.0** as you can see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). You will need to upgrade at least to **Tomcat 7.0.X**.

Comment: is upgrading to tomcat 7.0x make any changes to the old files i have ?

Comment: Not supposed to, of course keep an eye on your log files after upgrade!